# Docker .NET Web Application: "exec format error" during deploy on ARM64 Platform aws

Tags: asp.net, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm trying to containerize a new .NET web application using Docker and target the `ARM64` architecture. However, I'm encountering an error during the deploy of the fargate. I've provided the relevant details below:

Issue:

When running the following Docker build command:

```
docker buildx build --platform=linux/arm64 -f "./WebApplication2/Dockerfile" --build-arg CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN --force-rm -t yourname "."
```

I get the following error `exec /usr/bin/dotnet: exec format error`

[image]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication2/WebApplication2.csproj", "WebApplication2/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication2/WebApplication2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication2"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication2.dll"]
```

I created a simple .net web application and it does not work, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you configured your ECS task to deploy to ARM/Graviton? That error would indicate you built the image for ARM but deployed to X86, or vise versa. You do appear to be building the image correctly for ARM.

Comment: yes im sure it was a linux arm 64